# I converted the database file to a text file

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, assets

I accidentally converted my database file to a text file. When opened, it shows that I am using the wrong encoding format. Any help would be highly appreciated.

File screenshot

[image]

Comment: Its .`db file`  try to view it an online Sqlite Viewer .

Comment: You can check your db here follow this link http://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer/

Comment: thanks sir, I can see the data in the database, but whenever I put the db file again in the assets folder it does not work like its supposed to and its showing that the file uploaded is loaded in the wrong encoding..

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you have because :-

Android Studio has no built-in support for browsing SQLite databases and hence why it shows as it does. It would probably look similar in NotePad.

That is there is little reason why you would open a database in Android Studio (or any other editor (unlesss it is one that supports SQLite files)).

To re-assure you, here's an SQLite database I opened in Android Studio (and goth the same message) :-

[image]

If you loaded the file into/opened the file in a tool for browsing/managing SQLite databases then I would expect that the database will be accessible.

Opening the above database in an App allows the App to output the following from the database :-

```
04-02 10:25:18.979 1837-1837/? D/OADB-HLPR: logDatabaseTableInformation initiated.
    Database contains Table testtable created by SQL CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
        `_id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        `name`  TEXT,
        `timestamp` INTEGER
    )
    Table is testtable Column Count = 3 Row Count = 2
        Columns are :- _id name timestamp 
    Database contains Table sqlite_sequence created by SQL CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
    Table is sqlite_sequence Column Count = 2 Row Count = 1
        Columns are :- name seq 
    logDatabaseTableInformation completed.
```

As you can see a lot of the information matches the screenshot.

Likewise if you accessed the database in an app then again it very much looks as though it would be as expected.

From what is shown it appears that you have a table called QuestionBank, it has a column with a type of INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT as table sqlite_sequence exists. etc.

I say this because the first  characters are **SQLite format 3** as per :-

> 0 16  The header string: "SQLite format 3\000"

[Database File Format](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html)

One such tool that is commonly used is **DB Browser for SQLite**.